# Emacs Evil mode - How to remap 'hjkl'?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, spacemacs

I use Colemak keyboard layout and the conventional Vim 'hjkl' are not comfortable. In my .vimrc I've added the following to replace 'hjkl' with 'neio' (and *vice versa*).

```
noremap n h
noremap e j
noremap i k
noremap o l

noremap h n
noremap j e
noremap k i
noremap l o

noremap N H
noremap E J
noremap I K
noremap O l

noremap H N
noremap J E
noremap K I
noremap L O
```

If possible, how can I do this in Emacs with Spacemacs?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how `hjkl` are bound in `evil-maps.el`:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "h" 'evil-backward-char)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "j" 'evil-next-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "k" 'evil-previous-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "l" 'evil-forward-char)
```

You can put similar lines with your own keys in your `init.el` to bind the directions to whichever keys you want. You'll also need to rebind `hjkl`, assuming you don't want them left to their original direction bindings.

EDIT: to replace `hjkl` with `neio` I believe you'll need to unbind `i` and `o` in `evil-normal-state-map`:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "i" nil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "o" nil)
```

Comment: I first added the altered 'hjkl' and 'neio' to `init.el` but that didn't work. I then reverted the changes in `init.el` and changed keys directly in `evil-maps.el`. Same result. Other mappings seem to work but 'i' and 'o' can still not be used for movement. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

`hjkl` in qwerty is `hnei` in colemak, not `neio`. i see why you may want to use `neio` since that brings all arrows right under your fingers (instead of shifted one position to the left), but this is not necessarily a good thing: down/up (`jk` on qwerty) are frequently used, and use the two strongest fingers.

qwerty `hjkl` (colemak `hnei`) is actually pretty ergonomical, so for me it makes sense to keep this when using colemak. and of course unlearning many years of muscle memory is another reason to stick with it.

keeping `hnei` for navigation and sensibly dealing with the consequences is exactly what i achieved with my [evil-colemak-basics](https://github.com/wbolster/evil-colemak-basics) package. you may want to check out its documentation since it has an extensive write-up about the design. perhaps you will even end up using it. :)

Comment: Fair point. I recently came to the same conclusion myself: no need to have all the arrows under fingers as long as up/down are there. I might give `hnei` a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make these changes in .spacemacs. I couldn't find the 
evil-maps.el, but the [FAQ](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b6d52030b165fc5b74c95d2ade9f1ba6b5c15ab7/doc/FAQ.org) recommends changing them in user-config.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
;; colemak config
;; Make evil-mode up/down operate in screen lines instead of logical lines
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "i" nil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "o" nil)   ;;neio back,up,down,next
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "i" 'evil-next-visual-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "e" 'evil-previous-visual-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "n" 'evil-backward-char)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "o" 'evil-forward-char)
;; Also in visual mode
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "i" 'evil-next-visual-line)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map "e" 'evil-previous-visual-line)
```

Comment: wait! this is terrible.  Now you can't use insert state with "i".  What are you going to do, always use append state "a". ?   Nice Colemak motion, but seems to have a small problem.

Comment: This remapping is also handled by the evil-colemak-basics package. https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/7178

Comment: not exactly but it comes close: evil-colemak-basics uses a variation: keeps "hnei" for arrows, and aims for "muscle memory compatibility".

Comment: @wouterbolsterlee, after the merge you enable by choosing one of colemak-neio colemak-hnei colemak-jkhl and adding it to the layers list in .spacemacs?  I guess I wasn't a vim user that long. I think I want the navigation  on j i k l  like some old DOS game.

Comment: i do not use spacemacs, just plain emacs+evil. i doubt that spacemacs has my evil-colemak-basics package integrated. guess you can still use it for normal vim-style editing like delete/yank/navigate and so on, just not for the `SPC-...` commands.